# Speak phone did not work in MODE_IN_CALL in android version 4.2.2 more

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-audiomanager

I have a headset device and it connected to my phone. I tried to program to turn on the speaker of phone (Because I want to transfer my voice from the headset to my phone). However, It did not work although I called setSpeakerphoneOn(true). The problem is that the my voice is hear in my headset, instead of my speaker phone. Could you see my configure and let me know what is problem? Thanks

```
_audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
_audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
_audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL); 
_audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);

int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, maxJitter, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the below code to do the Remote alarm. The Phone sounds even after Headset is connected. Try it once.But not sure will this helps you.

```
AudioManager audioManager = 
            (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    DataFields.volume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);

    int max = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    Log.v("MAXVOLUME",""+max);
    int volume;
    while((volume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC))<max) {
        audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, 0);
    }
    int resID=context.getResources().getIdentifier("alarm", "raw", context.getPackageName());
    mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context,resID);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: The sound still transferred to my headset, hence I only hear my voice in my headset, although my voice is captured in my phone (I printed the packet in logcat)